# Multiple Prompts appears after resizing my terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, tmux, fish

I am using fish shell, with tide for the prompt, color and source code pro for glyphs.
[image: it looks like this]

[image: after resizing]

if I type clear or reset command it fixes, Is there any way for it to show correctly even after resizing, without explicit command.

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is this,
I want to use tmux with fish shell, with split terminals like this,
[image]
I think the error in the small terminals are direct consequence of the above.

the issue was raised here also : https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2320

I also tried this command by putting it into my bashrc and config.fish :

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="resize &>/dev/null; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

REF : [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res#:~:text=One%20way%20that%20works%20is,a%20virtual%20machine%20console%2C%20etc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res#:%7E:text=One%20way%20that%20works%20is,a%20virtual%20machine%20console%2C%20etc).

Comment: Does setting `fish_handle_reflow` to either 0 or 1 help? Try `set -Ux fish_handle_reflow 0` (and also 1). [More on this variable](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#envvar-fish_handle_reflow)

Comment: Hey, thankyou for your reply, I tried your suggestion but it did not work. anyways, can you suggest me some other ways to achieve the same thing or maybe some other promt library i can try instead of tide, or some other manager instead of fisher.

Comment: A simple thing you can run is `trap clear WINCH` which will automatically run `clear` when WINCH is delivered (i.e. the window is resized). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It worked man, oh my god, thankyou. I also added this command to my config.fish so that whenever terminal is opened, it automatically runs on open. thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with the right hand timestamp. You see the space between the time and the left margin exists as spaces. That's how they can display the time at the very right hand margin. When you expand the window, that space also expands and is filled in.

However, when you shrink the terminal, it doesn't know what to do with that space, since it no longer fits between the margins. Therefore, it causes the line to break over two, which I think is interpreted as a new line.

When you resize a terminal by dragging it, on MacOS or Linux, you're essentially resizing it lots of times; hence, lots of little lines. (You might notice that the number of unnecessary lines produced is equal to the dimension difference of the terminal resize).

The solution I opted for was to just delete the time on the right hand side as I didn't really care for it anyway.

To achieve this run `nano .config/fish/functions/fish_right_prompt.fish` and add this code:

```
function fish_right_prompt
 #intentionally left blank
end
```

You may need to adjust the directory based on how fish is stored on your system. This worked for me; I'm on a MacBook and installed fish through Homebrew.